# Why is the Recv-Q value in netstat equal to socket backlog + 1?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, netstat, backlog

When I execute `netstat -tulnp`, the output is as follows:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:43043        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2021            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22222           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8719            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
tcp      101      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
tcp       51      0 0.0.0.0:1234            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20891           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:55285        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

The value of Recv-Q caught my attention. After my investigation, I found that OOM occurred in the JVM application, and it can be found in the log that the http-nio-80-Acceptor-0 thread responsible for monitoring port 80 has exited, and the thread responsible for dispatching port 1234 requests has exited. The relevant logs are as follows:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-nio-80-Acceptor-0"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-5"
```

The default configuration used by tomcat, that is, the backlog is 100, and the source code is located at [tomcat/AbstractEndpoint.java at 8.5.59 · apache/tomcat · GitHub](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.59/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint.java#L538-L545):

```java
/**
  * Allows the server developer to specify the acceptCount (backlog) that
  * should be used for server sockets. By default, this value
  * is 100.
  */
private int acceptCount = 100;
public void setAcceptCount(int acceptCount) { if (acceptCount > 0) this.acceptCount = acceptCount; }
public int getAcceptCount() { return acceptCount; }
```

The listening of port 1234 is triggered and created by HTTPServer, and the created code is `HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(PROMETHEUS_SERVER_PORT), 0);`, backlog is corrected to 50 in `ServerSocket.java`, the source code is located at [jdk/ServerSocket.java at jdk8-b120 · openjdk/jdk · GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/net/ServerSocket.java#L369-L370):

```java
public void bind(SocketAddress endpoint, int backlog) throws IOException {
    if (isClosed())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    if (!oldImpl && isBound())
        throw new SocketException("Already bound");
    if (endpoint == null)
        endpoint = new InetSocketAddress(0);
    if (!(endpoint instanceof InetSocketAddress))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported address type");
    InetSocketAddress epoint = (InetSocketAddress) endpoint;
    if (epoint.isUnresolved())
        throw new SocketException("Unresolved address");
    if (backlog < 1)
      backlog = 50;
    try {
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (security != null)
            security.checkListen(epoint.getPort());
        getImpl().bind(epoint.getAddress(), epoint.getPort());
        getImpl().listen(backlog);
        bound = true;
    } catch(SecurityException e) {
        bound = false;
        throw e;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        bound = false;
        throw e;
    }
}
```

From [netstat(8) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html#:%7E:text=Listening%3A%20Since%20Kernel%202.6.18%20this%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20column%20contains%20the%20current%20syn%20backlog.) we know, Recv-Q indicates current syn backlog when socket is in `Listening` state, what confuses me is why Recv-Q is **one** more than the value of backlog we set?

Comment: So you ran out of memory, so your accepting thread stopped accepting, so the backlog queue grew to its maximum size. The thing to solve here is the OOM,, not the backlog queue.

Comment: @user207421 My question is why the value of Recv-Q is one larger than the preset backlog instead of equal to the backlog. Why are the values of Recv-Q 101 and 51 instead of 100 and 50?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this behavior in a C program and using `ss` instead of telnet. looking into it more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A backlog value of N really does mean allow "N + 1" connections
> to queue to a listening socket.  This allows one to specify
> "0" as the backlog and still get 1 connection.

Reference: [NET: Revert incorrect accept queue backlog changes. · torvalds/linux@64a1465 · GitHub](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/64a146513f8f12ba204b7bf5cb7e9505594ead42)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** netstat/ss is reporting complete and incomplete connections while the backlog is only concerned about completed connections

> we know, Recv-Q indicates current syn backlog when socket is in Listening state,

Yes this is confirmed in the `sock_diag` [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sock_diag.7.html#:%7E:text=are%20as%20follows%3A-,udiag_rqueue,-For%20listening%20sockets) page. It looks like netlink takes this value from the [following](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8efd0d9c316af470377894a6a0f9ff63ce18c177/net/unix/diag.c#L102) kernel structure:

```
rql.udiag_rqueue = sk->sk_receive_queue.qlen;
```

Looking into `qlen` more, it looks like it is not the same as backlog. The qlen includes complete and incomplete connection, while the backlog is only concerned with completed connections. The `listen` man page makes note of this:

> The behavior of the backlog argument on TCP sockets changed with
> Linux 2.2.  Now it specifies the queue length for completely
> established sockets waiting to be accepted, instead of the number
> of incomplete connection requests.

As for why the receive queue cares about incomplete connections, I can only speculate that it is trying to handle the edge case of a the backlog freeing up while the TCP handshake is still occurring.